# Threading slowdown camera operation of live streaming

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I am working on one project where I have implemented threading for processing images captured by the camera.

Please find the below code for `ProcessFrame()` which is called by the timer after some time Interval.

```
    private void ProcessFrame()
 {            
            try
            {
                 Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame;
                // Get Image from the camera
                ImageFrame = capture.QueryFrame();

              // check if imageFrame is null or not 
                if (ImageFrame == null)
                {
     // if null then re- initialize  the camera
                    try
                    {
                        capture.Dispose();
                        capture = new Capture(URL);                   
                        ImageFrame = capture.QueryFrame();                   
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }
               // resize image to show on Picture control
                ImageFrame = ImageFrame.Resize(img.Width, img.Height, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR);
    // show image on picture control
                img.Image = ImageFrame;
                try
                {   
     #region Making directory and image in this code
                    string VerifyImageFolderId = VerifyImageFolder + "\\" + "Camera_" + (1) + "\\";

                    if (!Directory.Exists(VerifyImageFolderId))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(VerifyImageFolderId);

                    string VerifyImageFileName = VerifyImageFolderId + "\\" + nSavedImagesCounter + ".jpg";
                    img.Image.Save(VerifyImageFileName); // Save Image
                    nSavedImagesCounter++;
                    #endregion

                    #region Starting thread For processing Image
                     Thread processImage = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => ProcessImage(VerifyImageFileName)));
                      processImage.Start();                    
                    #endregion

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log(ex.Message);
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    GC.Collect();
                }
                //#endregion
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException e)
            {
                Console.Write("Exception:\n" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmss"));
            }

        }
```

Here, is the second function `ProcessImage(string ImagePath)` which is use to perform some file processing operations as follows:

```
 private void ProcessImage(string ImagePath)
    {            
        #region Check for threadSafeFunction
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside InvokeRequired");
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { ProcessImage(ImagePath); }));
        }
        else
        {
1. Detect faces in Image 
    2. Draw Face markers on Image
    3. Some database based on result of Face Detection
    4. Delete image File            
        }

    }
```

After adding of the threading working of `ProcessFrame()` function  was slow down.
and I am not able to get the live streaming on display.

Can any one help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest you use queue for processing images
run this code once

```
     BlockingCollection<string> imageQueue=new BlockingCollection<string>();
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            foreach (string imagePath in imageQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                ProcessImage(imagePath);
            }
        }).Start();
```

and change ProcessFrame Like This

```
 private void ProcessFrame()
 {


        .....

                #region Starting thread For processing Image
                imageQueue.Add(VerifyImageFileName);
                #endregion

            ...

    }
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where Do I add the first code?

Comment: This code needs to run once you can put it in form load or if you have an initialize method for your you can put it in there

Comment: Thanks for your answer but can you explain 1st part of your answer.why it needs to intialise only once ?

Comment: Does it help? It creates a queue for processing imgae and wait for an image to process, once an image insert in collection it start to process it in another thread.and if there is more images to process they process in order ,one by one

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but when I am using it it process only a single image

Comment: Where did you add first part ?

Comment: `onFormLoad` of the main window where I want to stream my video

Comment: I recheck it , are you sure it processes only one image?

Comment: oops, Sorry it was my mistake it is processing all the images now actually for tracking the images I have to incremented my counter. Thanks for your support and answer too